# Android programming. Vibration/LED light Function

Tags: java, android

Hi I have created a task reminder application.  For example, you select a time of when to be reminded of a certain task, when that time comes, a notification comes up on the status bar.

However I would like to implement a vibrating function and possibly an LED light function with the notification but I am not sure where to start?  Does anyone know?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at the [Notification](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html) documentation? To set the led and have the phone vibrate, all you need to do is set the defaults field with the [DEFAULT_LIGHTS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#DEFAULT_LIGHTS) and [DEFAULT_VIBRATE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#DEFAULT_VIBRATE) values ORed together.

```
notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the code for creating and displaying the notification, the next lines of code will do:

```
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
```

More details can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html).

Answer (score 0):

Just quick google search Creating Status Bar Notifications http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html